# MS access pivot table get selected item vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, get, pivot-table, selecteditem

I've created a Form in `MS access` with a button and a `Pivot-SubForm`. When I click the button I would like to get the selected item in the pivot.
When the cursor is above, the item automatically appears a label with a string that I want to pass to the code, so I believe it is possible.

I have no idea, I didn't find anything on the web I'm in this point from `3W`.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2ef0e84-8679-480b-82e2-cca06b55a11d/access-pivot-table-click-event. Appears what you want is not possible.

Comment: Im not sure, I am not looking for the activation of an event related to the pivot. the triggher is the button. I would need something like  PIVOT.getvalue (field "Oda", seleted row) ti pur in click button event.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need that the event is fired by an external button, you can use the Form_Click() event on the pivot subform and examine the data of the pivot cell where the user clicked:

```
If Not Me.PivotTable.activeObject Is Nothing then
    If Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Field.Basename = "ODA" Then
        'Use the value Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Value 
    End If
End If
```

In this way, if the user clicks on the ODA value, you can get the value where the user clicked. You can also format the ODA column as an hyperlink.

Please note that you could also use Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Field.Caption or Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Field.DataField instead of Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Field.basename; I am not sure of the differences.

Also note that you can use other values from the same record by looking at Me.PivotTable.activedata.currentcell.Recordset![field_name]

(tested on Access 2010)